# Is this a common optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization

If I have code like this:

```
{
   int x = f();

   if (g(x)) return;

   int y = h();

   // use y
}
```

Will the compiler probably realize that x is not used after the `if` statement and that it can put the variable `y` in the register that `x` occupied? I know that all compilers are different, but the question is whether this is a common optimization that I can reasonably rely on. I am wondering because I want to let the optimizer elide the extra registers rather than having to come up with names like `this_variable_holds_x_then_y`.

Would it help to add an extra scope around `x` so that the compiler can see it's inaccessible from outside it?

Comment: Write clear, readable code and trust the compiler to do the right thing unless profiling proves otherwise.

Comment: This is so common that you'll probably implement it in your compiler course in university, if you study CS.

Comment: _Would it help to add an extra scope around x so that the compiler can see it's inaccessible from outside it?_ If X was an object, and you needed it "destroyed" before utilizing a constructed Y object, then definitely YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it's a very simple optimisation that any modern compiler would do.  You can also check easily for yourself - most compilers support a "-S" or other command-line option that produces assembly language output (or you can disassemble the machine code).

Comment: Would this come out in the wash of liveness analysis?

Comment: @CppMan probably, since this _is_ a liveness question. but I'd say "don't worry until it matters".